How do we change the "Time Trigger (Minutes)" in the milestone after the Case enters the entitlement?
I am new to Service Cloud and need some guidance.
I have a case that enters an entitlement when it is created, and there are milestones within the entitlement. I am using an Apex class with a time trigger to dynamically assign the "time trigger" minutes from a field called "Number of days" on the case.
I want to be able to change the Number of days field on the case and have it update the time trigger on a milestone named Total resolve time accordingly after the case enters the entitlement.
